# alert box like toast notification from a service

Tags: java, android, service, android-alertdialog, toast

Can I open a dialogBox from a service in android?
I want something like a Toast notification, but I want the possibility to close it when I want and not after some seconds like the Toast notification.

I need a "pop up " alert without focus, so the user can interacts with the application below

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this library [Crouton](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton)

Comment: nice, but I need to open an alertbox outside my application, for example when a call is coming

Comment: I see. Have you looked at DialogFragments http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html